# Change data-url via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to use jquery to change the `data-url` attribute used by a file upload. But it doesn't seems to be working. The file upload takes the old value.

`$('#fileupload').attr('data-url', "https://api.mysite.com/optimizeonly");`

HTML

```
<input id="fileupload" class="fileupload" type="file" name="file[]" data-url="https://api.mysite.com/upload" multiple="">`
```

Snippet:

```js
$('#fileupload').attr('data-url', "https://api.mysite.com/optimizeonly");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileupload" class="fileupload" type="file" name="file[]" data-url="https://api.mysite.com/upload" multiple="">
```

**Edit : 1**

I am using jquery file upload module , i though this was evident from the tags.
The whole code is available from the live demo (just inspect element)

Comment: I edited your question. Your code is working fine, you can inspect the element and see it in the snippet.

Comment: @chsdk the `data-url doesn't change...jquery is already included ....please refresh and look at the end

Comment: `jquery.data()` didn't work but `attr` did.Even though the data url change how come the post alraedy go to `/upload` instead of `/optimizeonly`

Comment: Maybe because the url update is done after page loading try to wrp your JS code in `$(document).ready(function)({ //Your code here });`

Comment: @chsdk its already inside a ready

Comment: jQuery's `.data()` is a bit tricky: if you do not have a HTML5 data- attribute declared for the element, then jQuery will modify the internal data without actually reflecting the changes in the DOM. However, in your case, since the `data-url` attribute is already specified, using `.attr()` or `.data()` should work just fine

Comment: @Terry i managed to make the data-url change but somehow the fileupload still make a POST to old data-url...ctrl + F5 and check the live demo

Comment: The `data-url` HTML5 attribute is not a standard--you must be using a third party plugin to handle file uploads. I do not see any inclusion of said plugin in your code example, so of course the attribute will not be used?

Comment: Perhaps use the list version: `$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: $(".fileupload").map(function() { return $(this).data("url") }) });` since the data-url is already consumed when you assign the fileupload to the element

Comment: @mplungjan where should i add this line.Can you post an answer

Comment: @mplungjan where should i add this line....?.Do a ctrl+F5 as there is just one document ready function

Comment: Where you do $(".fileupload").fileupload.... instead of autosubmit

Comment: @mplungjan i already have an add callback...can you please check my code and post your revision as an answer

Comment: On your page the submit is commented out. Anyway I do not have time to figure out how the fileupload works.

Comment: Could you add to the question that you are using a [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to handle the file upload? This is vital information for answering the question.

Comment: `data-url` means nothing here. Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input   The input doesn't have this attr. The question would be solved immediately after you posting **all** of your code.

Comment: @Justastudent I already indicated that i am using jquery file upload plugin in the tags

Comment: @blackmiaool live demo is provide just do inspect element

Comment: @user2650277 Yes, I noticed that after having looked at the question for some time. Not everybody looks at the tags. Just trying to help you improve your question :-)

Comment: @Justastudent Sure. This is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-url` attribute of the input is [read](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L1359) by the [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) when [initializing](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L1384). It is not automatically read afterwards. Have you tried updating the URL as follows?

```
var fu = $('#fileupload');
fu.fileupload('option', 'url', fu.data('url'));
```

Of course, this would be done after updating the `data-url` attribute of the element using

```
fu.data('url', 'new-url-you-want-here');
```

and you could, I think, skip updating the attribute altogether and only change the option of the plugin.

```
fu.fileupload('option', 'url', 'new-url-you-want-here');
```

Comment: Cheers! Is there anything I can improve in my answer to make it worthy of the bounty?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that restriction and thought you were missing something in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Can read the data-url property and revise it**

```
    var fu = $('#mainplayer');
    fu[0].dataset.url = "Hello";
    console.log(fu[0].dataset.url);
```