# Upload multiple image over a single in jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Currently when you drag and drop files or browse through files there is one xhr request for each file. How can I make the upload over a single xhr request.

The reason why I want to do so is that I want to process a series of images and then put them all in a zip and then give to user.

I want this to happen only when user ticks a checkbox.

[Live Demo](https://nowhide.me/design/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701743/jquery-file-upload-sends-each-file-in-individual-post-request

Comment: @mplungjan could you please post this as an answer.On another note can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043018/change-data-url-via-jquery .I managed to get the change in data-url working but somehow the file upload goes the POST to old data-url.check the live demo